# Why would a function that is defined on click, run on page load instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the first time I post on stackOverflow, and I really hope I don't mess it up.

I'm building a website using Compass, Foundation and jQuery, and I have a problem with my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function navOn(){
        //var navWidth = $('nav').outerWidth();
        //var contentWidth = $('.feed').outerWidth();
        $('.innerWrap').toggleClass('is-nav');
        $('.post').toggleClass('is-nav');
        $('.nav-main').toggleClass('is-nav');
        console.log("fu");
    };
    $('#tempSwitch').click(navOn());

    if($('.nav-main').hasClass('is-nav')){
        $('.feed').click(navOn());
    }

    $('.nav-menu a').on('click', function(){
        $('.nav-menu a').removeClass('is-active');
        $(this).addClass('is-active');
    })
});
```

When I load the document, I get the two console logs (Meaning the function ran twice), but nothing happens when I actually click the trigger I assigned.

Any ideas on why wouldn't this work?

**Edit:**
Thanks you all very much for your answers.

However, I'm trying to understand why, when I open the console and try to run navOn(), I get
ReferenceError: navOn is not defined

Also,

```
if ($('.nav-main').hasClass('is-nav')){
    $('.feed').click(navOn);
}
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `$('#tempSwitch').click(navOn)`. Remember, functions are objects (first class citizens).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your click bindings, you should be passing a reference to the `navOn` function object. Currently, you are *invoking* the `navOn` function, and passing the result (`undefined`) into the `click()` binder, which won't work for obvious reasons.

You should simply remove the parenthesis from your usages of `navOn()`:

```
...
$('#tempSwitch').click(navOn); // <= here
if ($('.nav-main').hasClass('is-nav')){
    $('.feed').click(navOn); // <= and here
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your indepth answer, it was very helpful.

However, I'm trying to understand why, when I open the console and try to run navOn(), I get
ReferenceError: navOn is not defined

Also, 
if ($('.nav-main').hasClass('is-nav')){
    $('.feed').click(navOn);
}

Doesn't seem to work.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Is your code identical to what you posted except for the fixes?

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you for sharing your most treasured commodities, your time and expertise.

As for your question, I believe so, you can find it here:
https://db.tt/yBhWMY20

Comment: This was an issue with scope; I defined the function inside the DOC.READY function - Problem solved

Answer (score 3):

remove the parens from `navOn()` in the click function `($().click(navOn))`

Answer (score 0):

The callback expects a pointer to be passed. What you are doing is actually invoking the function instead of providing a reference to it.

It should look like this instead:

```
$('.feed').click(navOn);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not passing the function to the click handler, rather you are actually calling that handler.

Instead of

```
 $('#tempSwitch').click(navOn());
```

Try doing

```
 $('#tempSwitch').click(navOn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
$('#tempSwitch').click(navOn);
```

Right now you're calling the function, not setting it as a handler.